# SQL Multiple Rows Data Keep in a Col

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a source sequence table like below

```
+----+-----+------+--------+
| ID |  No | Ref  | Amount |
+----+-----+------+--------+
| A  | 1   | abc  | 500    |
| A  | 2   | efg  | 400    |
| A  | 3   | def  | 600    |
| A  | 3   | ccc  | 600    |
| A  | 4   | bbb  | 600    |
| A  | 4   | bce  | 600    |
| A  | 4   | der  | 600    |
| B  | 2   | zzz  | 250    |
| B  | 5   | xcv  | 300    |
| B  | 5   | qwe  | 300    |
+----+-----+------+--------+
```

where ID, No and Ref are the primary key and I would like to change the source like below

```
+----+-----+-----------+--------+
| ID |  No | Ref       | Amount |
+----+-----+-----------+--------+
| A  | 1   | abc       | 500    |
| A  | 2   | efg       | 400    |
| A  | 3   | defccc    | 600    |
| A  | 4   | bbbbceder | 600    |
| B  | 2   | zzz       | 250    |
| B  | 5   | xcvqwe    | 300    |
+----+-----+-----------+--------+
```

The ref data will concatenate when Id and No are same, the Amount will remain same as first ID and No.

So anyone can provide the guidance to make it work.

Regards,

(PS: I am Novice in SQL)

Comment: @Wong This requires quite an advanced script, the answers given so far are the best way to do it, but don't be surprised if you don't understand them yet

Answer (score 2):

By combining `correlated subquery` and `For Xml path` you can do this.

`For xml path` will help you to convert your different rows into single row.

```
SELECT ID,
       No,
       (SELECT ''+Ref
              FROM   Tablename  B
              WHERE  a.ID = b.ID
                     AND a.No = b.no
              FOR xml path('')) Ref,
       Amount
FROM   Tablename A
GROUP  BY ID,No,Amount
```

The appended empty string is just to avoid the tag that will be created by `For XMl path`

Comment: no need for stuff in this case, this is only required for delimited strings to remove the leading delimiter

Answer (score 1):

```
select  id,no,Ref=Stuff((SELECT ' ' + ref FROM t t1 WHERE t1.id=t.id AND t1.no=t.no   

 FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '' ),
MAX(Amount) as Amount
from t
GROUP BY id,no
ORDER BY id,no
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba14c/7)

Answer (score 1):

Try using for xml :

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(ID VARCHAR(30), NO INT, REF VARCHAR(30), Amount MONEY)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES
('A',1,'abc',500),
('A',2,'efg',400),
('A',3,'def',600),
('A',3,'ccc',600),
('A',4,'bbb',600),
('A',4,'bce',600),
('A',4,'der',600),
('B',2,'zzz',250),
('B',5,'xcv',300),
('B',5,'qwe',300)

SELECT ID,
       NO,
       (SELECT '' + REF
        FROM   @table t2
        WHERE  t1.ID = t2.ID
               AND t1.No = t2.No
               AND t1.Amount = t2.Amount
        FOR XML PATH('')) AS Ref,
       Amount
FROM   @table t1
GROUP  BY ID,NO,Amount
```